# how to parse the json  responseString from webservice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am connecting to webservices using json.

I connected using nsurl connection. I got json response string ... i need to parse it.

When i try to parse it i am getting following error:

dyld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr

here is relevant source code:

```
  // Using NSURLConnection

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDzl0Ozijg2C47iYfKgBWWkAbZE_wCJ-2U&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures&callback=handleResponse"]]retain];    

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [myConnection start];    

    [super viewDidLoad];

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 

{

    [dataWebService setLength:0];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

    [dataWebService appendData:data];

}


    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 

    {

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);

        [responseString release];

        [dataWebService release];

    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

    {

        NSLog(@"Error during connection: %@", [error description]);

    }


    // Parse JSON    

     - (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {

        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];

        NSDictionary *dictionaryReturn = (NSDictionary*) [dictionary objectForKey:@"request"];   

        NSString *total = (NSString*) [dictionaryReturn objectForKey:@"totalResults"];


        NSLog(@"totalResults: %@", total);    

        int count = [[dictionaryReturn objectForKey:@"count"] intValue];

        NSLog(@"count: %d", count);        
    }
```

Comment: You expect us to find an code formatting issue in unformatted code you pasted in your question?

Comment: I think this: `[request responseString];` is where you go wrong. This guide might be helpful: http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c And please format your code!

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection or ASIHttpRequest. It looks like you are using both and none at the same time.

Comment: i am using NSURL connection for connecting..i got json response string which i need to parse

Comment: we should use NSURL connection and parsing of JSON in same class rite?

Comment: Check whether you’ve #imported the header file that declares `ASIHTTPRequest`: `#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"`

Comment: ok do i need add frameworks like systemconfiguration and other frameworks?

Comment: json returned this error:

    Parse error on line 1:
    //APIcallbackhandleR
    ^
    Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON response string is not a valid one, that's the reason your are getting the error.

Use the following link to check the if the JSON string, sent as response from Web services is valid one or not

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: no its valid one but i am getting error in ASIHTTPRequest that is 
"expected a type" and warning tat "responseString not found return type id"

Comment: it is a invalid one... i checked the URL specified in the code using JSONLint validator, it is returning as invalid JSON string.

Comment: hey i got all errors cleared but program is not running i hv edited the error and pasted which i am gettin... plz check it  if the URl is wrong plz give me the url string where i can get parse response string...plz i am not getting it

Comment: Just copy the URL of the web service in your code and paste it in the link i mentioned in my previous comment and check the validity of JSON String. That's it.